# Capistrano no access to directory

Tags: linux, deployment, centos, capistrano, capistrano3

When I'm trying to enable `systemd` service I got

```
DEBUG[a8223480] Command: ( /usr/bin/env sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/api.service )
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host MY_IP: sudo exit status: 1
```

The same happens when I manually try to:

```
execute :sudo, :ln, '-s', '/etc/systemd/system/api.service', '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/api.service'
```

or even when I touch file in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` directory.

However when I log in to my server I can execute any of above command.

Where is the problem?

Comment: what user is `capistrano` running as on the host? When you log on to the server is it as the same user?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. I can deploy my whole code, only this one command fails.